# preg_match() fails with string containing slashes

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have a function like this:

```
function in_array_r($item , $array){
        return preg_match('/"'.$item.'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}
```

and then I use it like:

```
if(in_array_r($row['name'], $items_array)){
   // something..
}
```

It works unless the `$row['name']` contains something like `blah / blah / something`, in which case it says that it can't find it in the array, even though it exists.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the slash in your input: `blah / blah / something` is seen as delimiter for the regex.

To solve this you can escape your input with [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), e.g.

```
function in_array_r($item , $array){
    return preg_match('/"'. preg_quote($item, "/") .'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you for assisting a dummy today :)

Comment: @user1996496 You're welcome. If you have error reporting turned on: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` you also would have get an error for that

Answer (score 0):

I know this in an old question, but I wanted to share that I resolved this, simply by using a different delimiter, e.g.

```
$var = 'string with /// slashes';
preg_match("~.*?$var.*?~i", $string);
```

This is a perfectly valid syntax in PHP.

Comment: This will not work if the string contains `~` character. It's much more secure to use `preg_quote`.

Comment: Sure, I can agree with that. In my case I'm only dealing with URLs, i.e. strings containing slashes, so tildes are never (or at least, shouldn't be) present.